# How to find number of overlaps for non-NA and NA among different columns using R

Tags: python, r

I am going to find the number of overlaps between some groups (arranged as columns of data set). In fact, I want to use these values to draw a venn diagram for my data. I require to count all non-NA values for each column and also the number of non-NA values overlapped between different columns (e.g group 1 with group2 or group1, group2 and group4, ..........). The content of cells is not important and I am not looking for common cells between columns. I just want to count non-NAs regardless of their content. Do you have any idea to do it using R or python.
example of part of data:
structure(list(V1 = c("Group1", "XP_032738419.1", "XP_032715310.1",
"XP_032703108.1", "XP_032700385.1", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), V2 = c("Group2", "XP_011286297.1, XP_011286306.1, XP_019670819.1, XP_019670818.1, XP_023097752.1, XP_011286308.1, XP_011286311.1, XP_023097760.1, XP_011286303.1, XP_023097755.1, XP_023097756.1, XP_023097757.1, XP_023097758.1, XP_023097754.1, XP_023097753.1, XP_011286310.1, XP_023097759.1, XP_019670826.1, XP_011286304.1, XP_019670828.1",
NA, "XP_019685915.1", "XP_023112367.1", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), V3 = c("Group3", "XP_038528678.1",
"XP_038300380.1", "XP_038538922.1", "XP_038295408.", NA, NA,
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), V4 = c("Group4",
"XP_012903997.1", "XP_004748105.1, XP_012909429.1", "XP_012905661.1",
"XP_012901919.1", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
NA, NA, NA, NA), V5 = c("Group5", "NP_001310871.1", "NP_001341201.1",
"NP_001374917.1", "NP_001123304.1", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), V6 = c("Group6", "XP_044098939.1",
"XP_044080143.1", "XP_044112499.1", "XP_044084408.1", NA, NA,
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c("1",
"2", "3", "4", "5", "NA", "NA.1", "NA.2", "NA.3", "NA.4", "NA.5",
"NA.6", "NA.7", "NA.8", "NA.9", "NA.10", "NA.11", "NA.12", "NA.13",
"NA.14"), class = "data.frame")

Comment: First: deine what you mean by "overlap". Second delete that image and replace it with output of `dput(dfrm, 20))`. I'm not the downvoter but my guess is that it has to do with someone's presumption that you have not read the help page where it says images of datasets are not welcome because they imply that it is our job to repeat **your** data entry..

Comment: Thank you. I mean the number of cells that are non-NA both in e.g. in first and second groups.

Answer (score 0):

The number of rows where both Group1 and Group2 are NA would be:

```
 sum( rowSums( is.na( dfrm[1:2]) ) == 2)
```

At least I hope it would be. `is.na(.)` applied to a dataframe (or subset of a dataframe as I attempt here) should return an equivalently dimensioned, logical dataframe and then you can test whether a rowSum of logicals (1=TRUE, 0=FALSE) is 2. Then you add them up. Regular R code is best read from the inside out as this demonstrates. The `magrittr`/`tidyverse` language variant of R reverses the arrangement of arguments and functions.  You should still delete the image and post [MCVE], and ideally you would [edit] your question so that the clarifying information in your comment would be made available for persons searching for similar help.